# What is the density of integers of the form $a^2+nb^2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Landau proved that the mean density of integers of the form $a^2+b^2$ up to $x$ is $K\frac{x}{\sqrt{\log x}} (1+o(1))$, where $K$ is an explicit constant. One proof is based on the fact that a prime $p$ is of this form iff $p\neq 3\mod 4$, and so we can express the generating function for these integers in terms of the zeta function and the $L$-function of the non-trivial character modulo $4$. From there one proceed using complex analysis.

For integers of the form $a^2 + nb^2$, one should have similar results. We know what primes has this form by class field theory, and then in principle one can continue as before.

I am sure this is classical, but unfortunately I've failed to find it in the literature (including google). **Does anyone know a reference for this?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is quite a bit in the literature on this problem. Apparently it was first solved by Bernays in his 1912 PhD thesis under Landau. The density is as expected (namely proportional to $x/\sqrt{\log x}.$)

A modern paper on the topic is:

Brink, Moree, Osburn - Principal forms $X^2+nY^2$ representing many integers.

This contains many useful references about the history of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

R. W. K. Odoni has his own proof of the theorem, [see this paper on the problem](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0025579300005945),

> "On norms of integers in a full module of an algebraic number field and the distribution of values of binary integral quadratic forms",

published in Mathematika 22 (1975), no. 2, 108–111. See [Narkiewicz's review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=389856). Odoni's paper does not appear in the paper mentioned by Daniel.

The concluding remarks in Odoni's paper are very interesting and refer to some earlier partial results.